# Reasoning behind ArrayIsStoredDirectly rule of PMD

Tags: java, security, code-analysis, pmd

PMD has a rule called ArrayIsStoredDirectly in the Sun Security ruleset:

> Constructors and methods receiving arrays should clone objects and store the copy. This prevents that future changes from the user affect the internal functionality.

Here is their example:

```
public class Foo {
 private String [] x;
  public void foo (String [] param) {
      // Don't do this, make a copy of the array at least
      this.x=param;
  }
}
```

I don't think I completely understand the reasoning behind this rule. Is it because the values in the array passed can be altered somewhere else? Is there a difference between passing a Collection vs passing an array in regards to this?

Comment: No difference in regards to passing array vs Collection. A slight difference in secure treatment of arrays and Collections is that with arrays it's ok to call .clone(), but you shouldn't trust the .clone() method of a Collection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the caller may keep a copy of the array argument that it passed, and can then change its contents.  If the object is security critical and the call is made from untrusted code, you've got a security hole.

In this context, passing a collection and saving it without copying it would also be a potential security risk.  (I don't know if there's a PMD rule to tell you this.)

In both cases, the way to address the risk (if it is real) is to set the attribute to a copy of the argument array or collection.  On the other hand, if you know that the caller is always going to be trusted code, the copy is a waste of time, and a better solution would be to tell PMD to be quiet about that particular method.

Comment: Thanks. I got confused that PMD was complaining about directly setting an array but not about collections and thought that I might be missing some understanding in regards to the handling of arrays vs collections.

Comment: I dont think passing a collection would be a security risk. Because if you're worried about untrusted code you can use a immutable collection. But a raw array cannot be immutable.

Comment: @gabe - There are two cases that you need to consider.  1) You pass bad code a collection and it modifies it.  2) Bad code passes you collection and modifies it behind your back.  Passing an **unmodifiable** collection guards against 1) but not 2.  (There is not immutable collection class in Java ... only unmodifiable ... and the difference is significant.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no differnce between passing a collection or an array: in both cases sender and receiver can modify the content of the datastructure. Here's an example:

```
// ... in some method
Foo myfoo = new Foo();
String[] array = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
myfoo.foo(array);     // now the Foo instance gets {"One", "Two", "Three"}

array[1] = "Changed"; // now the internal field x in myfoo is {"One", "Changed", "Three"}
```

If you do not want this behaviour, you have to, following this PMD rule, clone the array in Foo and store a reference to the clone. This way you make sure, that no other class holds a reference to your internal array (unless we forget about reflection for a moment and unless we don't return this internal array in another method...)

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem with arrays is that you **can not** control acces to it.

But with a Object you hide members behind setters where you **can** control what will be set. I think the same applies to Collections because you need to call `add()` and `toArray()` returns a copy.